# Midpoint with a connected subset and continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Given a connected subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^p$ and a continuous function $f:A\to \mathbb{R}$.  If I have points $b,c \in A$ and a point $x \in \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies $f(a) < x < f(b)$,  how do I show that there is a point $c \in A$ such that $f(c) = x$?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the one indicated.  You can clearly see the questions are not similar.

Answer (score 1):

The continuous image of a connected set is connected. Thus $f(A)$ is a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and hence must be an interval. Since $f(a), f(b) \in f(A)$, this interval must contain the interval $[f(a),f(b)]$. In particular $x \in f(A)$, i.e. there is $c \in A$ such that $f(c)=x$.